# Install isolated ROR application on apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I decided to make an experiment. I created a simple rails app on one Ubuntu system. I used RVM and used bundler the way to put everything in one place:

```
$ bundle package
$ bundle install –local –path vendor
```

Than I copied the project directory do another Ubuntu pure system. I installed RVM, apache2, passenger, etc. But I didn't install rails as there was such a gem in my project dir.

After configuring apache and visiting http://localhost/test which was supposed to show my project page i saw nothing but errors..

```
A source file that the application requires, is missing.

    *
      It is possible that you didn't upload your application files correctly. Please check whether all your application files are uploaded.
    *
      A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.

Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.

Error message:
    no such file to load -- bundler/setup
Exception class:
    LoadError
Application root:
    /home/anonym/Desktop/gemtest2/test_1_8_7 
Backtrace:
    #   File    Line    Location
    0   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
    1   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
    2   /home/anonym/Desktop/gemtest2/test_1_8_7/config/boot.rb     6   
    3   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
    4   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
    5   /home/anonym/Desktop/gemtest2/test_1_8_7/config/application.rb  1   
    6   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
    7   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
    8   /home/anonym/Desktop/gemtest2/test_1_8_7/config/environment.rb  2   
    9   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
    10  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
    11  config.ru   3   
    12  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rack/builder.rb   46  in `instance_eval'
    13  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rack/builder.rb   46  in `initialize'
    14  config.ru   1   in `new'
    15  config.ru
```

Can this be fixed without installing rails on the system? (Don't ask me why, I'm just experimenting with ROR :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to configuration was the key:

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /home/anonym/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.11
  PassengerRuby /home/anonym/.rvm/bin/passenger_ruby
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you still need bundler itself to be installed.

Comment: Really? I just installed ruby 1.9.3 and bundler wasn't installed for me (although it's entirely possible that it's an optional extra).